# Azure Function In-Portal editor is unreachable, can't access though Kudus

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

I am unable to access my Azure Function which I created in-portal. I can't get to the Kudus [image: gives me this error]

I created the function in-portal I don't have the backup for the code I created in the portal. I need to get access to the code.

I did change the Azure Storage keys that were associated with the function, as new keys were generated due to some reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check if WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING appSetting has the right connection string?   Restart the site.   You can also go to Azure Files (using Azure Portal) to see/download your content.

Comment: After updating the keys from the func-settings I was able to access the code the func ran smoothly